# Fastest Software Gamma=2.2 for RGB?

Tags: graphics-programming, srgb

With gamma=2.0 you can use that Carmack's inverse sqrt hack or a lookup table. Yet all standard graphic formats mandate the use of gamma=2.2, and SVGA framebuffer also requires it. Unfortunately, for gamma=2.2 a linear lookup table doesn't fit into CPU cache (it is a whooping 192 kilobytes). So should one work with gamma=2.2 directly or convert it into gamma=2.0?

The question of course assumes that everything is done in software, because modern GPUs support gamma=2.2 in hardware. I want to avoid using OpenGL, because it is non-portable unstable API, and a total overkill for a simple 2d indie game.

Comment: My CPU is from 10 years ago and it has a 1MB L2 and 6MB L3 cache. Why wouldn't it fit?

Comment: You must be confusing something. I've Intel core i5, which has just 64 KB of L1 cache, and 256 KB of L2 (per core). It indeed has several MB of L3 cache. And accessing L3 cache is about 23 times slower than L1 cache. I.e. difference between L1 and L3 is the difference between 1 frame per second and 23 frames per second.

Comment: 192Kb < 256KB however I look at it

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked these?  It should be very quick and easy to set up a comparison of lookup table vs just calculating it directly; you might be surprised by the result.

Comment: I just want to mention that the whole point around OpenGL is to be portable, and it can increase performance even on 2D games. Most (cross platform) libraries out there that focus on 2D games use OpenGL in the background.

Comment: I don't have Windows and Linux, so I use bochs emulator to compile for these platforms. Now bochs emulator has no 3d acceleration, only SVGA frame buffer, so anything using OpenGL will fallback to Mesa3d on Linux and won't be working on Windows at all. FreeBSD and HaikuOS have no 3d acceleration either, even on real hardware. Smartphones have their own OpenGL ES version, incompatible with desktop OpenGL, which is also know to deprecate important features, like texture combiners. Nothing can beat simple set_pixel(x,y,color) in portability. Therefore the best solution is to avoid using GPU.

Comment: @SmugLispWeenie - I think you're setting yourself too high an ambition here - "I want to run on everything" is not a realistic, achievable goal for someone at your level.

Comment: It is a realistic goal, if you avoid using OpenGL/DirectX, and go 100% set_pixel. Now porting code would be just a matter of porting set_pixel. Your game would run even on a bare metal x86 with VESA, if you manage to boot from a ROM. And turning off page translation would also make your game running faster, because MMU and context switches incurs rather large cost.

Comment: It's not realistic because SetPixel is typically not fast. By the time you go down the "make it fast" route you'll have implemented 80% of a hardware-accelerated framebuffered API.

Comment: SetPixel was fast enough for Quake 1, so it will be fast enough for a 2d indie game. I remember even games like Unreal Tournament 2004 had software rendering in year 2004, so...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to compress any large gamma magnitude back to 8-bits.

First one has to convert said magnitude to a custom floating point format, and then use it as an index into a small lookup table.

Loss of precission is not a huge problem, because values are mapped to 8-bit RGB components anyway.

Here is the code for a custom 16-bit float:

```
#define CFP_MANTISSA_BITS  11
#define CFP_MANTISSA_MASK  ((1<<CFP_MANTISSA_BITS)-1)
#define CFP_EXPONENT_BITS  (16-CFP_MANTISSA_BITS)
#define CFP_POINT (CFP_MANTISSA_BITS-1)
uint16_t int2cfp(uint32_t n) {
  int e = log2(n) - CFP_POINT; //log2 is basically x86 BSF's or ARM's CLZ
  if (e < 0) return n; //can be replaced by a table
  return (e<<CFP_MANTISSA_BITS) | (n>>e);
}

uint32_t cfp2int(uint16_t n) {
  return ((uint32_t)n&CFP_MANTISSA_MASK)<<(n>>CFP_MANTISSA_BITS);
}
```

That way the size of a lookup table can be made to match cache size perfectly.

Half-floats can also be used for that purpose, but they have a max value of (float)0xFFFF, so one must normalize them before lookup. Both ARM and x86 have fast float-to-half float conversion instructions, which can be accessed from C/C++ using the following code:

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
__attribute__ ((__target__("f16c"))) uint16_t x86_f2h(float value)
{
  return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm_cvtps_ph(_mm_set_ss(value), _MM_FROUND_CUR_DIRECTION));
}
```